# javascriptでアラート表示

Tags: javascript

以下のオンクリックの時に、バリデーションアラートを作動させたいのですが、どのようにすればうまくいきますでしょうか。詳しい方、ご教示ください。宜しくお願い致します。

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.insert.submit()" id="senddiv">保存する</a> 


<form id="form" method="post" name="insert" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="tags" id="tags">
</form>


<script>
$(function(){


    $('#form').submit(function() {

        if($('[name="tags"]').val() == ''){
            alert("タグを記入してください。");
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

aタグのonclick属性値を以下にすると良いと思います。

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#form').submit()" id="senddiv">保存する</a>
```

これでJavaScript内で仕掛けているイベントハンドラが呼び出されるようになると思います。

Answer (score 0):

Safariで動かなくてもよければ、

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=submit value="保存する"><br>
<label>タグ: <input name="tags" required></label>
</form>
```

これだけでほぼ目的は達せられると思います。JavaScriptは不要です。